# Avoid duplicate names in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am fetching data from a table and binding to a label and Drop down in a gridview but i want to filter the duplicate names from the table and assign the corresponding dates to the DDL how can do this? or else is there any other alternative?

```
 private DataSet get()
    {
        string sql = "select Id,Name,RunDate from Historytable";
        SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

[image]

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    { 

        //what to code here?


        }
```

Comment: dates means Datetime value from the table

Comment: It would be better if you can also show the table structure and data

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get back only unique names from your HistoryTable you should use the keyword DISTINCT

```
string sql = "select DISTINCT Name from Historytable";
```

however, seeing your update I think you should change your query to something like the proposed answer of @dasblinkenlight, if you want the first date for each name

```
string sql = "select Min(ID), Name, Min(RunDate) from Historytable group by Name";
```

or (if you want the last date for each name)

```
string sql = "select Max(ID), Name, Max(RunDate) from Historytable group by Name";
```

Comment: I just want to get all the data into a dataset or a list and i want to avoid the duplicate names and assign the datetime to DDL

Comment: Could you add to your question some sample data?

Comment: yeah updated the question even i have to avoid the duplicate names and i have to fill DDL with all rundates for that name

Comment: I just posted this as a example i will be using stored proc for fetching data

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the design of your UI. You want a DDL filled with all the dates belonging to a particular name, but how do you choose the current name? Do you have another DDL which contains only the names?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way of removing duplicates is as follows:

```
string sql = "select min(Id),Name,min(RunDate) from Historytable group by Name";
```

This eliminates all rows where a duplicate `Name` with a numerically smaller ID exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not needing the ID for anything, you can set the objectdatasource for the gridview in its selected event to a dictionary, using a little LINQ to group things up:

```
Gridview1_ObjectDataSource_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {
   DataSet ds = get();

   Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>(); 

   var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(row => new { name = row.Field<string>("name"), RunDate = row.Field<DateTime>("RunDate") })
                          .GroupBy(r => r.name)
   foreach (var group in rows) {
      dict.Add(group.Key, group.ToList());
   }
   e.ReturnValue = dict;
}
```