# Filling Drop down list based on name

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid duplicate names in a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090398/avoid-duplicate-names-in-a-dataset)

I am fetching data from a table and binding to a label and Drop down in a gridview but i want to filter the duplicate names from the table and assign the corresponding dates to the DDL how can do this? or else is there any other alternative?

How to bind the DDL based on label name??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Bind the DDL based on Label name drag and drop the ddl in visual web developer, Click "choose data source" 
Choose your data source and where it sais Display value  choose "name" Where it sais value choose "rundate"
that will bind the name to the drop down list while binding the date as its value.

Im pretty sure this is what you were asking if not please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove duplicate names . so I select distinct names and rundate according to that by using partition by close . partition by close create partition according to name and give row number to it .
then i select all records with row number 1 . it will remove all duplicate names . try to run following query

```
SELECT RUNDATE , NAME
FROM
(
SELECT RUNDATE , NAME , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) AS CNT
FROM TABLENAME
) AS A 
WHERE
CNT = 1
```

now you can bind datavalue property of DDL to RUNDATE and datatext property to Name . it will definitely solve your problem .